# R loop for mediation function and summary capture?

Tags: r, loops

Is it possible to have a loop in R run a rolling mediation and summary capture?

The apply.rolling function in the PerformanceAnalytics package won't work because of the complexity in the multivariable mediate function and capturing the summary into a table.

Each mediation spans 336 rows of data:

```
Afrah.timelapse.1_336.model.m <- lm(Aridia.Faction.Kills$Afrah[1:336] ~ Aridia.Ship.Jumps$Afrah[1:336])
Afrah.timelapse.1_336.model.y <- lm(Aridia.Faction.Kills$Afrah[1:336] ~ Aridia.Ship.Kills$Afrah[1:336] + Aridia.Ship.Jumps$Afrah[1:336])
set.seed(1)
Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation <- mediate(Afrah.timelapse.1_336.model.m, Afrah.timelapse.1_336.model.y, treat="Aridia.Ship.Jumps$Afrah[1:336]", mediator="Aridia.Ship.Kills$Afrah[1:336]", sims=1000)
summary(Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation)
summary(Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation) %>%
capture.output() %>%
discard(`==`, "") -> lines
Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF <- data.frame(lines[which(grepl("^ ", lines)):(which(grepl("^Sample", lines))-1)] %>%
sub("^   ", "Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation", .) %>%
gsub("95. CI Lower", "95_CI_Lower", .) %>%
gsub("95. CI Upper", "95_CI_Upper", .) %>%
sub(" \\(", "_(", .) %>%
sub("p-", "p_", .) %>%
sub(" ", "_", ., fixed=TRUE)  %>%
textConnection() %>%
read.table(header=TRUE))
Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.table.row <- data.frame('Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation',Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,5],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,5],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,5],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,5])
names(Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.table.row) <- c("Med_Area","ACME_Est","ACME_95pCIL","ACME_95pCIU","ACME_pv","ADE_Est","ADE_95pCIL","ADE_95pCIU","ADE_pv","TE_Est","TE_95pCIL","TE_95pCIU","TE_pv","PM_Est","PM_95pCIL","PM_95pCIU","PM_pv")
write.table(Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.table.row, file="H:/System.Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.table.row.csv",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,sep=",")
Afrah.timelapse.table[nrow(Afrah.timelapse.table)+1,] <- c('Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation',Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[1,5],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[2,5],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[3,5],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,2],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,3],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,4],Afrah.timelapse.1_336.Mediation.DF[4,5])
write.table(Afrah.timelapse.table, file="H:/System.Afrah.timelapse.rolling.table.csv",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,sep=",")
```

The only multivariable examples that I've been able to come across for R involve nested for loops and unless I'm misunderstanding them (quite possible), nested loops wouldn't work for the mediate function or the summary capture, but would work for the table writing parts.

My hatchet method thus far as been to copy the above and search/replace the '1_336' and '1:336' with their consecutives (e.g. '2_337' and '2:337'), but that's hardly sustainable or efficient.